# Infinite direct sums in k-linear categories

Tags: category-theory, direct-sum

Are there any universal properties of infinite (countable) direct  sum in k-linear category? I'm looking for some properties which will help me to build mappings to and from the direct sum if I have mappings to or from all components of the sum. May be direct sums in k-linear categories are products or coproducts?

And I want to know more about direct sum in general, for example, I don't understand the motivation of this concept. Could you, please, recommend me some books, where I can find information about it?

Comment: It's simply the coproduct of the given objects.

Comment: Indeed, and if you know what a coproduct is, you should now understand the motivation for a direct sum.